# В чем разница между EDITIONABLE и EDITIONING представлениями?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

На синтаксической диаграмме создания представления:

[image: Blockquote]

видно три способа создания:

1. `EDITIONING`
2. `EDITIONABLE EDITIONING`
3. `NONEDITIONABLE`

В чем разница между созданием `EDITIONING` и созданием `EDITIONABLE EDITIONING` представлений?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Difference between editionable and editioning views?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65612533) от участника [@kritika arora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12029125/kritika-arora)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65612533

Answer (score 3):

- `EDITIONING` - это тип представления, то есть - тип обьекта в БД
- `(NON)EDITIONABLE` - это свойство некоторых типов обьектов в БД

---

Эти клаузы относятся к [Переопределение на основе редаций](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/high-availability/ebr.html) (EBR=*Edition-based redefinition*).

EBR вводит концепцию редакций. Оно расширяет пространство имён для объектов БД. Теперь полное квалифицированное имя объекта:

```
edition_name.schema_name.object_name
```

Таким образом, один объект может иметь множество определений в одной и той же схеме. Имя `edition_name` является частью настроек сессии, добавляется неявно, оно не может быть указано напрямую.

Редактирующие представления (*editioning views*) - это специальный тип представления, используемый для поддержки изменений схемы с нулевым временем простоя. Это своего рода обёртка для базовой таблицы, которая позволяет
в каждой редакции иметь свою проекцию таблицы, и тем самым, каждая из них видит только *свои колонки*. Код приложения должен быть изменён, чтобы доступ к базовым таблицам был только через эти представления. На них распространяется [ряд ограничений](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30__GUID-E89B1B60-CBCB-4C3F-B30C-6B24B7CBD15B):

> - Within any edition, you can create only one editioning view for any single table.
> - You cannot specify the object_view_clause, XMLType_view_clause, or BEQUEATH clause.
> - You cannot define a constraint WITH CHECK OPTION on an editioning view.
> - In the select list of the defining subquery, you can specify only simple references to the columns of the base table, and you can
>   specify each column of the base table only once in the select list.
>   The asterisk wildcard symbol * and t_alias.* are supported to
>   designate all columns of a base table.
> - The FROM clause of the defining subquery of the view can reference only a single existing database table. Joins are not permitted. The
>   base table must be in the same schema as the view being created. You
>   cannot use a synonym to identify the table, but you can specify a
>   table alias.
> - The following clauses of the defining subquery are not valid for editioning views: subquery_factoring_clause, DISTINCT or UNIQUE,
>   where_clause, hierarchical_query_clause, group_by_clause, HAVING
>   condition, model_clause, or the set operators (UNION, INTERSECT, or
>   MINUS)

На редактирующие представления можно создать межредакционные триггеры (*cross-edition triggers*). Они  используется для сохранения колонок, присутствующих в одной редакции, но отсутствующих в другой.

Ключевые слова `EDITIONABLE/NONEDITIONABLE` применяются к обычным видам представлений. Они определяют, может ли каждая редакция иметь свою собственную версию представления ("подлежит редактированию"), или все редакции должны иметь одну и ту же версию представления ("подлежит редактированию").

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65615842) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>